# Calling angular function from dynamically added hyperlink

Tags: angular, function, hyperlink, click

I'm adding some html dynamically to my page.
I have add this

```
<a [routerLink]="[]" class="image-fav" (click)="imageDel()">CLICK-ME</a>
```

Click on this hyperlink should call the imageDel function but it does not do so.

If I add this html to component template straight everything works fine.
How can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular doesn't understand the events of dynamically added elements. One workaround would be to use `ElementRef`'s [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) function to add the event handler. Try the following

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.image-fav').addEventListener(
    'click', this.imageDel.bind(this)
  );
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use `Renderer2`'s [`listen`](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2#listen) method or [`HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener) to bind the event handler.