# Calling angular function from dynamically added hyperlink which is added asyncronously

Tags: angular, function, hyperlink, initialization, click

While ngOnInit i call function which asyncronously gets me variable.
after that I want to create some hyperlinks on components template page using that variable data.
And that hyperlinks must call some function on click.
That part is not working because of

```
Angular doesn't understand the events of dynamically added elements
```

[Calling angular function from dynamically added hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108704/calling-angular-function-from-dynamically-added-hyperlink/62108779#62108779)

But that solution will not help me because ngAfterViewInit() do not get my variable which is made asyncronous.

So how can I do the followoing...

```
ngOnInit() {

this.somefunction gets me variable .subscribe( 
this.testVar='testData';
And here I construct some hyperlinks using this variable
<a [routerLink]="[]" class="image-fav" (click)="someFunc()">this.testVar</a>
}

someFunc() {
doing something....
}
```

Comment: The `ngAfterViewInit` from the other answer hook was a general use-case scenario. In your case, you could add the element to the DOM, trigger change detection (eg. using `detectChanges()`) and add the event listener like the other answer all in the `ngOnInit` hook.

Comment: @Michael, can u write simple example ?

Comment: I've wrote an example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works just like I wanted! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adapt the previous answer to your scenario. The `ngAfterViewInit` from the other answer hook was a general use-case scenario. In your case, you could add the element to the DOM, trigger change detection (eg. using `detectChanges()`) and add the event listener all in the `ngOnInit` hook.

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, ElementRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.someFunction().subscribe(
      response => {
        this.testVar = 'testData';
        // construct dynamic element `<a [routerLink]="[]" class="image-fav" (click)="someFunc()">this.testVar</a>`
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.image-fav').addEventListener(
          'click', this.someFunc.bind(this)
        );
      },
      err => {
        // handle error
      }
    );
}
```